# Trouble using python environment

Tags: python, command-line-interface

I'm having trouble using [RVC-CLI](https://github.com/blaise-tk/RVC_CLI)

I'm having trouble using [RVC-CLI](https://github.com/blaise-tk/RVC_CLI)
It says:

> Execute the install.bat file to activate a Conda environment.
> Subsequently, launch the application using env/python main.py instead of the conventional python main.py

I can't figure out what exactly should I do to set up the whole project in windows (start environment and main.py in particular).

I have tried launching it from cmd but it keeps coming up with error:

1. python main.py [windows] - Error with parselmouth
2. python3 main.py [linux] - Error numpy1.21 can't be reinstalled
3. env/python main.py [windows] - 'env' is not recognized...
4. conda - 'conda' is not recognized...

Tree of the folder - https://anonymfile.com/71xD/tree.txt

Comment: Needs a little more info; what error are you getting? What have you tried so far, and in what directories?

Comment: I'm a bit lost. If you are so kind, can you ask me questions which will clarify things for you? Main main question is how to launch anaconda environment in this project

Comment: "Do X [...] instead of the conventional python main.py"  and then you are doing `python main.py` which is exactly what the instructions tell you not to do

Comment: @FunnyShark45; you say that the method you're using is returning errors. These errors can help troubleshoot what the problem you're encountering is, such as if you have a missing file or files, if a package isn't working, and so on. It also helps to know what you've tried so far, so that we don't advise something you've already tried and failed.

Comment: When i try to run it on my windows machine I get "No supported Nvidia GPU found", but it does not crash the program. Then it is printed that "No module named 'parselmouth' ", when i try to install it i get "error in googleads setup command: use_2to3 is invalid". On my linux machine numpy 1.21 is required, but i get "RECORD file not found" when trying reinstall/uninstall it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try `conda help` in cmd. If this says something along the lines of Conda not being installed, you maybe should start the installer again?

To activate the enviroment you can use `conda activate base` and then you should be able to run `python main.py`.

That's for conda alone, I don't know the Package you are using specific, but you could def. try this.

Edit: Have you tried as suggested by you output using `env/python main.py` or `base/main.python` instead of `python main.py`?

Comment: I have already started installer a few times, but it doesn't change anything. Conda is still not recognized as a command. I have tried to enter "env/python main.py" - "'env' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." - Same with base/main.python